# ORACLE SQL: After Update Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Problem Statement:

Create a trigger named `trigger_contact_af_update` that is triggered whenever the `contact` table is updated. This trigger will insert the `org_name` and action into the table `contact_log_history` after the update of contact details. The action name in the affected log table `contact_log_history` is `After_Update_Contact`.

The query I have at the moment is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  trigger_contact_af_update
AFTER UPDATE ON contact
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO contact_log_history (org_name, action) Values (:OLD.org_name, 'After_Update_Contact');
END;
```

But it's not working. Can someone please tell me why?

The table `contact_log_history` has only two columns.

Comment: "*It's not working*" is not a valid Oracle error message.

Comment: I don't get any error messages. The trigger simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: Mmm, would you kindly try : `ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name ENABLE;`

Comment: Can you show the definition of the contact_log_history table?

Comment: @ Sagi the trigger is enabled

Comment: @ Lamar contact_log_history table: org_name varchar(30), action varchar(30)

Comment: @prince - Are you sure you're testing this trigger, whenever you're actually `UPDATE`ing the Contact table and not `INSERT`ing into it ? If so - is the trigger in a `VALID` state? You should paste the code you use to test this, so we assess if you're doing the actual test right.

Comment: Oh, one thing that gets me sometimes - you might need to put `SET DEFINE OFF` before your `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` line. Some sql clients will try to fill in `:OLD` as a substitution variable when running the create script. Also I usually put a trailing slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using the :OLD variable only works when using a before trigger. I would recommend you to do that in your case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  trigger_contact_af_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON contact
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO contact_log_history (org_name, action) Values (:old.org_name, 'After_Update_Contact');
END;
```

Comment: Update Contact set Org_name = 'some' where ID =1;

Comment: And you can update without any errors? Are you using a casesensitive System like Linux for your Databaseserver?

Comment: yeah yeah I am able to.. and no just on Win7

Comment: hang on a sec I'll check that on a Testserver

Comment: Does the trigger successfully compile?

Comment: try writing ":OLD" in lowercase

Comment: @FabianSteiner, this answer is only true for INSERT statements. From the docs, `A trigger fired by an UPDATE statement has access to both old and new column values for both BEFORE and AFTER row triggers.`

Comment: @kfinity with insert statements there is no new and old because there has never been such data before when you insert something. In general it makes more sence to log something before writing the changes.

Comment: All I had to do was add a '/' after END...But thanks anyways guys for helping out